# How to implement detekt with convention plugin and make detekt run with prebuild?

Tags: android, kotlin, gradle

I need help to configure detekt with convention plugin, I successfully registered detekt with convention plugin, but im stuck on how to make detekt as a prebuild tasks

im expecting detekt to can run everytime i build my project